# Math.random specific values corona sdk

Tags: random, lua, coronasdk

I have a set of pre-declared values to set specific rotations for an object.

```
local rotations = {900,-900}
```

And want my spawn function for the blocks to randomly pick one or the other from this function:

```
local blocks = {}
timerSrc = timer.performWithDelay(1200, createBlock, -1)

function createBlock(event)
   b = display.newImageRect("images/block8.png", 20, 150)
   b.x = 500
   b.y = math.random(100,250)
   b.name = 'block'
   physics.addBody(b, "static")
   transition.to( b, { rotation = math.random(rotations), time = math.random(2700,3700)} )
   blocks:insert(b)
end
```

When I use:

```
 rotation = math.random(-900,900)
```

it just chooses any values between the 2 numbers rather than 1 or the other. How can I do this correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `m` is an integer value, [`math.random(m)`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.random) returns integers in range [1, m] randomly. So `math.random(2)` returns integers `1` or `2` randomly.

To generate random numbers either `900` or `-900`, use:

```
rotation = math.random(2) == 1 and 900 or -900
```